# Why does storing &str in a Box<dyn Any> and downcasting it to a &Box<&str> always result in None?

Tags: struct, rust

I want to create a vector of structs each of which contains a field that can have any (multiple) type, being able to extract those values too. I've tried this:

```
use std::any::Any;

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Any>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(Box::new("test"));
    v.push(Box::new(3i32));

    let string: &Box<&str> = &v[0].downcast_ref().unwrap(); // erroneous line

    println!("{}", string);

    let int: &Box<&i32> = &v[1].downcast_ref().unwrap(); // probably gives an error too

    println!("{}", int);
}
```

It should print out

```
test
3
```

Instead, it panics:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:8:51
```

From what I understand, it downcasts to `&str` and unwraps to give `&Box<&str>`, except it returns a `None` value.

I've tried other stuff such as structs with generics but that's limited to only 1 type:

```
struct Item<T> {
    item: T,
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Item<&str>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(Item { item: "hi" });
    v.push(Item { item: 3i32 }); // error because it can only be &str, not i32
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not hold `Box<&str>` in `Any`. You hold `&str` in `Any`.

```
let string: &str = v[0]
    .downcast_ref::<&str>()
    .unwrap();

println!("{}", string);

let int: &i32 = v[1]
    .downcast_ref()  // Rust infers ::<i32>
    .unwrap();

println!("{}", int);
```